# how to find the general soultion using reduction of order?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I'm trying to find the general solution using reduction of order for this ode

$$y′′ + 2y′ + y = e^{-x}$$

i have found the complementary soultion :
$$c_1e^{-x}+c_2e^{-x}x$$
but im unsure how to use reduction of order method to find the paticular soultion

Comment: that was part of the reason why i was confused but the question asked specifically to use reduction I will copy the question  below just incase it adds any more clarity q3)Using the method of reduction of order, find the general
solution of the following ODE:
y′′ + 2y′ + y = e^(−x).

Comment: there was no more information than what was given, I was thinking it had something to do with the repeated root in the complementary solution but I'm unsure

Comment: I think the method they are describing is what is more commonly called variation of parameters. It has some features in common with what I would call reduction of order, which as I understand is a method to get another homogeneous solution when you already have one.

Answer (score 1):

Since $e^{-t}$ satisfies $$y′′ + 2y′ + y = 0,$$
a particular solution should be of the form
$$y_p=at^2e^{-t}$$
which is easy to get $a=\frac12$. Then the GS is
$$ y=(c_1+c_2t)e^{-t}+\frac12t^2e^{-t}. $$